# Tensorflow: Bug when using `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou`

Tags: tensorflow

I'm getting a strange error when trying to compute the intersection over union using tensorflows `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou`.
This was the code I was using before which works perfectly fine

```
tensorflow as tf
label = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file('/path/to/label.png'),channels=1)
label_lin = tf.reshape(label, [-1,])
weights = tf.cast(tf.less_equal(label_lin, 10), tf.int32)
mIoU, update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou(label_lin, label_lin,num_classes = 11,weights = weights)
init = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
sess.run([update_op])
```

However when I use a mask like this

```
mask = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file('/path/to/mask_file.png'),channels=1)
mask_lin = tf.reshape(mask, [-1,])
mask_lin = tf.cast(mask_lin,tf.int32)
mIoU, update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou(label_lin, label_lin,num_classes = 11,weights = mask_lin)
init = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
sess.run([update_op])
```

It keeps on failing after an irregular number of iterations showing this error:

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f29d0022fd0 ***
```

I checked the shape and data type of both `mask_lin` and  `weights`. They are the same, so I cannot really see what is going wrong here.
Also the fact that the error comes after calling `update_op` an irregular number of times is strange. Maybe TF empties the `mask_lin` object after calling several `sess.run()`'s ?
Or is this some TF bug? But then again why would it work with `weights`...

Comment: This sounds like a TensorFlow bug. Please fill out the [issue template on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new) with details of how to reproduce the problem, and somebody will take a look.

Comment: It looks like you posted it as https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8818 ... thanks!